# bash prompt messed up

Tags: bash, prompt

Today I had to install a couple of applications (a Postgres client and other stuff) and I had to setup a few things like environment paths.

I had a couple of aliases working and they stopped working after that. They are set on `~/.bash_profile` so I've run `source ~/.bash_profile`, but then I got my bash prompt messed up, like this:

[image]

This is the command within my `bash_profile`  that generates it:

```
export PS1="\[${BOLD}${MAGENTA}\]\u \[$WHITE\]in \[$GREEN\]\w\[$WHITE\]\$([[ -n \$(git branch 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo \" on \")\[$PURPLE\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$WHITE\]\n$symbol\[$RESET\]"
```

As you can see, the `\[`s and `\]`s are appearing, when they should not be displayed at all, and the `\u`, `\n`, and `\w` are not being replaced with the appropriate strings.  But the colour changes are still working.

I'm a bit confused about what's going on here, any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, and what did you try to do ?

Comment: Yeah you changed your PS1 variable and now the prompt look's different - change it back, or just type `export PS1="> "` to have a cleaner prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some expert thought it a good idea to obfuscate ANSI color codes in environment variables and use them in a custom prompt, meanwhile messing up the escape syntax, then setting the prompt "for you" without asking.

Comment out the PS1 line and you should get a default prompt. Or change it to something you prefer, but better don't rely on custom environment variables.

Related:

- [How to change the format of the bash prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386404/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-bash-prompt)
- [What color codes can I use in my PS1 prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-ps1-prompt/124409)